# Behaviourspace - Measure Runs every X steps?

Tags: netlogo

I am running a series of experiments using behaviourspace and outputting my results in spreadsheet mode. My model runs at a temporal rate of 1 day per tick. Every 365 days a year variable increments. I would like to report the value of another variable to the spreadsheet at the end of each year.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this using the behaviourspace "Measure Runs using these reporters" box? It seems that I can either report the value at every tick or at the end of the model. Ideally I would like to report every x ticks.

I have attempted to put a conditional statement in the reporters box but behaviourspace throws an error. An alternative option would be to create a list as the model runs and export it at the end of each run - but this produces unwieldy output for analysis. Is this my only option or am I missing something?

Any advice much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can report occasionally. Instead, I would do the following:
In your code, define a function called yearly-report and always report a value.

```
to-report yearly-report
 ifelse (ticks mod 365) = 0
    [report your-calculation-here ]
    [report ""; where "" is an empty placeholder text that you may ignore.]
end
```

Then in your behavior-space commands, call yearly-report

Comment: The [NetLogo FAQ](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#everynticks) explains how to run _all_ metrics every n ticks, but if you only want _some_ of the metrics run at an interval, I think Matt's answer is the best you can do. Note that defining a procedure isn't strictly necessary; you could also just use `ifelse-value` (instead of `ifelse`) directly in the metric.

Comment: Thanks guys - the above does work - it's shame we can't restrict this to an if statement - thus removing the 1000s of superfluous rows of "" in the output (and the memory implications if I do lots of replications). Not to matter - I can pull them out in a post process of the data. Cheers

Comment: Just to follow up on this - Seth, as ever, solved the problem - somehow I initially misinterpreted his link to the FAQ - but running `repeat 365 [ go ]` in the go section of behaviourspace does exactly what I need. Matt, apologies if my question wasn't clear and you thought I needed asynchronous reporters - that would be confusing. Thanks again chaps - appreciate it.